# Open Refine: Exporting nested XML with templating

Tags: openrefine

I have a question regarding the templating option for XML in Open Refine. Is it possible to export data from two columns in a nested XML-structure, if both columns contain multiple values, that need to be split first?
Here's an example to illustrate better what I mean. My columns look like this:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| https://d-nb.info/gnd/119119110;https://d-nb.info/gnd/118529889 | Grützner, Eduard von;Elisabeth II., Großbritannien, Königin |
| https://d-nb.info/gnd/1037554086;https://d-nb.info/gnd/1245873660 | Müller, Jakob;Meier, Anina |

Each value separated by semicolon in Column1 has a corresponding value in Column2 in the right order and my desired output would look like this:

```
    <rootElement>    
       <recordRootElement>
        ...    
            <edm:Agent rdf:about="https://d-nb.info/gnd/119119110">
               <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zxx">Grützner, Eduard von</skos:prefLabel>
            </edm:Agent>
            
            <edm:Agent rdf:about="https://d-nb.info/gnd/118529889">
               <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zxx">Elisabeth II., Großbritannien, Königin</skos:prefLabel>
            </edm:Agent>
        ...
        </recordRootElement>
        <recordRootElement>
        ...    
            <edm:Agent rdf:about="https://d-nb.info/gnd/1037554086">
               <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zxx">Müller, Jakob</skos:prefLabel>
            </edm:Agent>
            
            <edm:Agent rdf:about="https://d-nb.info/gnd/1245873660">
               <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zxx">Meier, Anina</skos:prefLabel>
            </edm:Agent>
        ...
        </recordRootElement>
    <rootElement>
```

(*note: in my initial posting, the position of the root element was not indicated and it looked like this*:

```
<edm:Agent rdf:about="https://d-nb.info/gnd/119119110">
    <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zxx">Grützner, Eduard von</skos:prefLabel>
</edm:Agent>
        
<edm:Agent rdf:about="https://d-nb.info/gnd/118529889">
     <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zxx">Elisabeth II., Großbritannien, Königin</skos:prefLabel>
</edm:Agent>
```

)

I managed to split the values separated by ";" for both columns like this

```
{{forEach(cells["Column1"].value.split(";"),v,"<edm:Agent rdf:about=\""+v+"\">"+"\n"+"</edm:Agent>")}}
{{forEach(cells["Column2"].value.split(";"),v,"<skos:prefLabel xml:lang=\"zxx\">"+v+"</skos:prefLabel>")}}
```

but I can't find out how to nest the splitted skos:prefLabel into the edm:Agent element. Is that even possible? If not, I would work with seperate columns or another workaround, but I wanted to make sure, if there's a more direct way before.

Thank you!
Kristina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to expand the answer from [RolfBly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016065/rolfbly) using the [Templating Exporter](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/exporting#templating-exporter) from OpenRefine.

> I do have the following assumptions:
>
> 1. There is some other column left of *Column1* acting as record identifying column (see first screenshot).
> 2. The columns actually have some proper names
> 3. The columns *URI* and *Name* are the only columns with multiple values. Otherwise we might produce empty XML elements with the following recipe.
>
> [image: Screenshot of expected data]

We will use the [information about records available via GREL](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/expressions#record) to determine whether to write a `<recordRootElement>` or not.

### Recipe:

1. Split first *Name* and then *URI* on the separator ";" via "Edit cells" => "Split multi-valued cells".
2. Go to "Export" => "Templating..."

[image: Screenshot of the templating export dialog from OpenRefine]

In the *prefix field* use the value

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rootElement>
```

> Please note that I skipped the namespace imports for `edm`, `skos`, `rdf` and `xml`.

In the *row template* field use the value:

```xml
  {{if(row.index - row.record.fromRowIndex == 0, '<recordRootElement>', '')}}
    <edm:Agent rdf:about="{{escape(cells['URI'].value, 'xml')}}">
      <skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zxx">{{escape(cells['Name'].value, 'xml')}}</skos:prefLabel>
    </edm:Agent>
  {{if(row.index - row.record.fromRowIndex == row.record.rowCount - 1, '</recordRootElement>', '')}}
```

The *row separator* field should just contain a linebreak.

In the *suffix* field use the value:

```xml
</rootElement>
```

Comment: Great, thank you - I'll try that! 
What does the "escape" function do? I have never used this one before.

Comment: The escape function (https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions#escapes-s-mode) escapes special characters that might break the structure of the xml file.

Comment: It should be noted that your first step, going from right to left splitting cells, is actually much better than my idea of exporting and concatenating.

Comment: I guess this has something to do with the "record" behavior of OpenRefine, which for splitting is also active in the "rows" mode. If you have another column left of *Column1", therefore acting as "record" column, you can also split the multivalued cells from left to right

Comment: I tried it out, and while getting the skos:prefLabel correctly nested works really well, the data that is now split into several rows gets exported to different records in my XML instead of the same. I tried the record mode and row mode, but the outcome is the same. I also see, that I was not clear enough in my intital post, how the data should be structured in the resulting xml, sorry!
As I have multiple rows with cells like my example above, all resulting pairs of edm:Agent/skos:prefLabel from one row, should be children of the same record root element. I'll fix that in my post.

Comment: The question evolves. So the data on each row does belong together? You could split each columns by `;` and rewrite your template, with first edm params Column 1-1 and Column 2-1, and the second edm params Column 1-2 and 2-2.

Comment: One more thing: please mark the answer that answers your question best. That's StackOverflow etiquette. You'll help people build reputation.

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly. Please note that if you have more complex requirements, like more multi valued fields in other colums the recipe will not work as expected because it might produce empty XML nodes. For more advanced XML exporting you'd need nested for-loops.

Comment: Great, thank you, I'll have a look at your updated answer this week!

Comment: That works great, thank you very much! I'll check, if it works together with the rest of my template, because in my original table, there are other rows as well. but I'll keep you comment about for-loops in mind.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: If you're keen on using *only* OpenRefine, this won't be the answer you were hoping for. There may be ways in OR that I don't know of. That said, here's how I would do it.

**Edit** The trick is to keep URL and literal side by side on one line. [b2m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16592991/b2m)'s answer below does just that: go from right to left splitting, not from left to right. You can then skip steps 2 and 3, to get the result in the image.

1. split each column into 2 columns by separator `;`. You'll get 4 columns, 1 and 3 belong together, and 2 and 4 belong together. I'm assuming this will be the case consistently in your data.
2. export 1 and 3 to a file, and export 2 and 4 to another file, of any convenient format, using the custom tabular exporter.
3. concatenate those two files into one single file using an editor (I use Notepad++), or any other method you may prefer. Several ways to Rome here. Result in OR would be something like this.

[image: tabular view of URL and text side by side]

You then have all sorts of options to put text strings in front, between and after your two columns.

In OR, you could use *transform* on column URL to build your XML using the below code

(note the `\n` for newline, that's probably just a line feed, you may want to use `\r\n` for carriage return + line feed if you're using Windows).

```
'<edm:Agent rdf:about="' + value + '">\n<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zxx">' + cells.Name.value + '</skos:prefLabel>\n</edm:Agent>'
```

to get your XML in one column, like so

[image: formatted column producing XML]

which you can then export using the custom tabular exporter again. Or instead you could use *Add column based on this column* in a similar manner, if you want to retain your URL column.

You could even do this in the editor without re-importing the file back into OR, but that's beyond the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thank you! Putting the URL and the literal in one column was one of my workaround ideas. But adding the \n directly in the cell saves some formatting, thanks! :)


That's the cell's content: https://d-nb.info/gnd/119119110">
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zxx">Grützner, Eduard von;https://d-nb.info/gnd/118529889">
<skos:prefLabel xml:lang="zxx">Elisabeth II., Großbritannien, Königin    |

and with would be my templating to split and nest the cell again:

{{forEach(cells["Column1+2"].value.split(";"),v,"<edm:Agent rdf:about=\""+v+"</skos:prefLabel>"+"\n"+"   </edm:Agent>"+"\n"+"   ")}}

Comment: Ok, I am having some formatting issues here... Sorry that it looks so mashed together.

Comment: Just a tip: put backticks ` (accent-grave) around inline code to make it more readable. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code-spans) for more on markdown.